# Pyrogram - Get all members in a channel with more than 200 members

Tags: python, bots, pyrogram

I have a channel with more than 200 members and I'm trying to get all of them.

I know that `iter_chat_members` has the limit of 200 members, so I'm calling `get_chat_members` multiple times by increasing the offset like this:

```
    # Get members count
    members_count = client.get_chat_members_count(chat.id)
    # Retrieve them
    members_offset = 0
    while members_offset <= members_count:
        members = client.get_chat_members(chat.id,
                                          limit=200,
                                          offset=members_offset)
        # Do something with the members...
        members_offset += 200
```

However, I continue to get only the first 200 members (when `members_offset` is greater or equal to 200 I get zero members from `get_chat_members`).

Is there a way to get all members from a channel with more than 200 members using multiple calls?

Thanks

Comment: The limit of 200 members is server-side, as the docs also mention. As far as I remember, Telethon has a way to bruteforce this, but this isn't a good idea to try and circumvent.

Comment: Ok, so basically there is no way to get them? I cannot even do multiple calls and get 200 members per call until I get them all?

Answer (score -1):

i know a way but i've never tried:

```
for member in app.iter_chat_members(YOUR_CHAT, filter="all"):
    # Do your stuff with member object
```